# How to get android mobile IMEI number using Dart language in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I need to get android mobile IMEI number using Dart language in Flutter. How to get this slot1 or slot2 IMEI number from Android mobiles.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [device_information](https://pub.dev/packages/device_information) package. For this package to use you need to ask for phone permission from the user. So add the below permission in your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

The second step is to get the user's permission to access their phone's info. Check the below code for permission:

```
Future<String> _askingPhonePermission() async {
  final PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getPhonePermission();
}

Future<PermissionStatus> _getPhonePermission() async {
  final PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.phone.status;
  if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
      permission != PermissionStatus.denied) {
    final Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissionStatus =
        await [Permission.phone].request();
    return permissionStatus[Permission.phone] ??
        PermissionStatus.undetermined;
  } else {
    return permission;
  }
}
```

And finally, use the above-mentioned package to extract the device's IMEI number.

```
String imeiNo = await DeviceInformation.deviceIMEINumber;
```